# Allocated/Unused data disk space VM Wise

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

```
(get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName "<rgname>" -Name "vmname>").StorageProfile.DataDisks
```

Or

```
((get-azurermvm -resourcegroupname "<rgname>" -name "vmname>").StorageProfile).DataDisks.DiskSizeGB
```

But this is showing only the size of data disks. I want to get the Allocated and Unused data disk space.
 Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to list all blobs in that storage account, you can use this PowerShell command `Get-AzureStorageBlob` to list all blobs, like this:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$RGName = "ResourceGroupName"
$SAName = "storageaccountname"
$ConName = "containername"
$TempObj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject
$TempObj |Add-Member -Name BlobName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $null
$TempObj |Add-Member -Name LeaseState -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $null
$Keylist = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RGName -StorageAccountName $SAName
$Key = $Keylist[0].Value
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SAName -StorageAccountKey $Key
$List = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob *.vhd -Container $ConName -Context $Ctx
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, But I really need to get unused space of vhds (Data Disk only) attached to the VMs.
My final requirement is to get a list of Unused space Data Disks attached to VMs, so we can use that report use save that to filling that. 

Like it will show:
VM - myvm
Size - 120GB
Unused - 10GB
#means more tha 90% filled I need to do something for that#